# Setting InfoWindows for markers, with geocoding in a loop

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

The code below is working. But it isn't using the standard function initialized and that's why I am not able to use online examples to make custom info windows for each address on the map.

How must I define it in order to have it working?

```
var address = <?php echo json_encode($adr); ?>; //define address array here
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoom: 10
});    
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var image = 'http://www.site.com/images/hi.png';
var nbAddresses = address.length;
for (var i=0;i<nbAddresses;i++){
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address[i]
    }, 
    function(results, status) {
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title:"Hello"
            });
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You aren't placing an infowindow anywhere in the code. Can you define your requirement again?

Comment: Yes Cdeez, I tryied to call infowindow function diffrent ways and had no succeed, so that's why I left clear working code above and hope someone to include the missing part with example of infowindow popup and to place it where it has to be within the code above - I am sure I can customize it after that.. Hope you understand the core of my request, thank you !

Comment: Ok. You need the infowindow on click event of marker or should it be placed as you create it?

Comment: onclick event please , thank you again !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Javascript that should do the work

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ytM6h/1/)

**Script:**

```
geocoder.geocode({
        'address': add
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            mark = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map
            });
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            setInfoWindow();
        }
    });

    function setInfoWindow() {
        google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function(event) {
            var iwindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            iwindow.setContent(event.latLng.lat() + "," + event.latLng.lng());
            iwindow.open(map, this);

        });
    }
```

**Update:**
Used loops to demonstrate how to assign title value to the maker after Geocoding success-

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ytM6h/3/)

The key here is that the loop variable used for fetching addresses isn't available in the scope of the sub function, so you need to create a global variable and increment it to fetch new values from the array for titles.

Comment: great job ! :) I customized it to my addresses and it is working.. There is one last issue with this: 'address': add is an array. How do I loop within js a php array for titles for each marker on the map. For example I have $title[] php array, how to get each address his own title with js code above. Once again huge Thank you ! You safed my week :)

Comment: I have no idea about php. In asp.net usually the array is converted to a javascript array and then used like you use `address[i]` for address. Similarly covert the php array to js array(_a little googling should do_) and you should be able to set titles the same way.

Comment: Cdeez, sorry for confusing you, I was not clear with my question. Php array I convert to js array by using json: var title= <?php echo json_encode($title); ?>; After I alert(title) I receive the array with titles, but since I am not familar with js scripting I do not know how and where to loop it and than how and where to include it.. It is probablly super simple but as I said I am not familar with js at all.. :)

Comment: I am new user here and as such can not upvote, but only accepted your answer :( sorry for not beneficialing you !

Comment: I have the following at the top: var title = <?php echo json_encode($ttl); ?>;
and    new google.maps.Marker({    
    position: results[0].geometry.location,    
    map: map,    
    icon: image,    
    title:titles[i]    // i will denote the index in the array
    });    
replaced and get no errors but no titles on the markers as well, what could be the problem? I have no other code related to titles..

Comment: May be a typo, it should be `var titles` as per the code. If that isn't the issue, possibility is that your titles array isn't having values/the array isn't available in this scope

Comment: dear cdeez, may I email you the full js code to test it because it is not working on some reason without errors. I tryied to publish it but could not manage the requirement for pasting code

Comment: maybe the loop is not OK - I do this on the top: 
var titles = <?php echo json_encode($ttl); ?>;
for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++)
alert(titles[i]);
and the alert gives me 7 titles / 7 alerts as it should be, but in the marker :
title:titles[i]
doesn't show the titles.. PLEASE help me last mate :)

Comment: Hey sorry I just missed a basic rule. See the update. Your issue is solved now.

Comment: Man You r the best ! Issue is solved, until the next one comes up :)))
Really I appreciate your help Cdeez!!!

Comment: hello again Cdeez,
I wanted to add titles for each InfoWindow having its own title and added this: 
var contentString = titles[x];
to the list of variables but all addresses show same title.. What could be the reason? function setInfoWindow looks like:
    function setInfoWindow() {

        google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function(event) {
            var iwindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            //iwindow.setContent(event.latLng.lat() + "," + event.latLng.lng());
   iwindow.setContent(contentString);
            iwindow.open(map, this);
   });
  }

Comment: You should post it as a new question. Adding up issues to the same question isn't allowed.

Comment: Not sure if this question makes sense, but thought of asking anyways. since this is an asynchronous call, it is possible that you may get result back from call for "for loop i=5" before i=4 isn't it? if yes, then this is an issue because global variable wont match with i. Hope i explained my doubt clearly.